# Weird error when trying to generate migration with TypeORM for the first time

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, database-migration

I am using TypeORM with nestjs. I tried to run migration:generate to do a migration for the first time (around 30 tables), but I got an weird error.

```
Error during migration generation:
QueryFailedError: unsupported: '*' expression in cross-shard query
 at Query.onResult (.../node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:158:37)
    at Query.execute (.../node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (.../node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (.../node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (.../node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
  query: 'SELECT * FROM (\n' +
    '                SELECT\n' +
    '                    *\n' +
    '                FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` `kcu`\n' +
    '                WHERE\n' +
    "                    `kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'goodturtle-db'\n" +
    '                    AND\n' +
    "                    `kcu`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'AcademicStatus'\n" +
    '             UNION \n' +
    '                SELECT\n' +
    '                    *\n' +
    '                FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` `kcu
(about 2 thousand lines more...)
```

Here are the typeorm versions I am using

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
"typeorm": "^0.3.11"
```

I assumed that my entity declaration is correct because the tables are created when I turn on the synchronize flag.

Thanks for your help and please let me know if I have to provide additional information.

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The version is 8.0.28.